# Automatic migrations multiple services one database

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I need some assistance. While talking with a co worker on the benifits of EF automatic migrations and he stumped me with a question. What happens if you are using automatic migrations in a load balanced enviroment and two contexts are attempting to migrate sql at the same time. He thinks the db could lock up. I am not sure how to test this scenario has anyone encountered this configuration before?